# obtener los valores 0 en consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estimados,

tengo un proyecto de encuesta para alumnos en cual hay una tabla form_alumno en donde ingresan los alumnos de forma anónima y llenan un formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego se redirecciona a la encuesta, cual consta de 21 preguntas y cada pregunta tiene 5 tipo de respuestas(1,2,3,4,5).

Tengo la siguiente consulta que es para rescatar la suma de la cantidad de cada tipo de respuesta por cada pregunta y ademas un filtro por curso, año y semestre:

```html
SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas 
                        FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
                        WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '342139' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
```

arroja esta tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que la tablas me arroje los valores 0 la tabla debería quedar asi:

```html
Id_respuesta  tipo  cantidad_respuesta
     1         1           0
     1         2           0
     1         3           0
     1         4           4
     1         5           3
     2         1           0
     2         2           0
     2         3           0
     2         4           2
     2         5           5
     |         |           |
    21         1           0
    21         2           1
    21         3           2
    21         4           2
    21         5           2
```

cualquier orientación o ayuda sera buena de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas 
                        FROM preguntas p 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta 
                        
                        LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo

                        LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
                        
                        WHERE f.cod_curso_alumno = '342139' AND f.anio = '2016' AND f.semestre = 'Primer'
                        
                        GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
```

La solución era agregar debajo del WHERE 
or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL or anio IS NULL or semestre IS NULL.
Por si alguien alguna vez tenga la misma duda.